# weird java.io.NotSerializableException

Tags: java, serialization, servlets

I have a abstract class `A` which implements `Serializable`.

There is another concrete class `B` which extends the `A` class.

In the constructor of the `B` class I create an instance of class `C` (`public final class C` ).

`C` is throwing wierd exception like this:

```
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: C
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1164)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1518)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1518)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:330)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.writeObject(StandardSession.java:1572)
```

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 4):

I am guessing `C` is not Serializable and you are setting it in a non-transient field. You need to make the field transient or `C` Serializable.

Comment: What do u mean by field..? what field r u talking about..?

Comment: you mean you don't know what a field is? how did you reach serialization?

Comment: If the `C` object is failing to be serialized it is because you set a field to reference it. I am assuming B is not a inner class of C.

Answer (score 1):

class `C` is not `Serializable`. Either make it `Serializable` or mark the field as `transient`